# Number of stationary areas for polynomial of many variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, stationary-point

Suppose we have a polynomial $f$ of $k$ variables of degree $n$. $\mathcal S$ is a set of stationary points, on which equation $\nabla f=0$ holds. What is the maximum number of connected components of $\mathcal S$.

For example, for ($k=2$, $n=2$):
$$
f(x,y)=x^2
$$
$\mathcal S$ has one connected component.

Comment: It would be better if you made a certain example.

Comment: Could be infinitely many if $k \ge 2$ and $n \ge 2$, e.g. $f(x,y) = x^2$.

Comment: What I really meant is how many distinct areas are there with zero gradient. In example $f(x,y)=x^2$ there is one area with zero gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Let be $p$ a one variable polynomial with $r$ zeros (for example...). Consider the polynomial
$$f(x,y) = \int p(x)\,dx.$$
How many connected components has your $S$?